# Найти цикл минимального веса в неориентированном взвешенном графе

Tags: алгоритм, graph

Понятно, как это можно сделать за О(n^4) c помощью стандартного алгоритма Дейкстры. Но хотелось бы узнать, существует ли алгоритм который решает эту задачу быстрее. Думал, что можно как-нибудь модифицировать алгоритм Дейкстры, чтобы он вычислял минимальное расстояние от какой-то вершины до этой же самой вершины, но что-от ничего толкового в голову не пришло. Подскажите, как можно решить эту задачу быстрее, чем за О(n^4).

Comment: Флойда бери. Получится куб.

Comment: @Qwertiy, алгоритм Флойда в стандартном виде не считает расстояния от вершины i до вершины i. Но спасибо, сейчас попробую его немного изменить.

Comment: Пока что Флойдом тоже не получилось, завтра еще попытаюсь. Буду рад, если кто-нибудь еще озвучит свои идеи по поводу задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой алгоритм (доказательством корректности не интересовался):

Из каждой вершины K запускаем Дейкстру, получаем дерево кратчайших путей, и теперь для каждого ребра AB, **не входящего** в это дерево *(можно получить из массива  предков)*, находим

```
 T = weight(K-A) + weight(AB) + weight(K-B)
```

и выбираем минимум из всех T

Получается сложность `V * (V^2 + E + E) ~ V^3`

Comment: Спасибо.  Утром такая мысль тоже появилась)